# How to avoid refreshing the page using a form_tag in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form with slide bars which have values per default (`value` in the code under ). When I click the submit button it calculates the results correctly or when I change the default values manually. The thing is when changing the default values manually, it refreshes again the page and set the values to their default value.

The form is this one, which I have in a partial view for ordering purposes.

```
<%= form_tag() do %>


          <h2>J  <a id="dialog-1" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <div id="slider-jahresverbrauch"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module1", params["user_entry_module1"] || "", id: "amount-jahresverbrauch", disable: true, class: "amount", size: 2 %>  
          <span>kWh</span>

          <h2>PV  <a id="dialog-2" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <div id="slider-pvgrosse"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module2", params["user_entry_module2"] || "", id: "amount-pvgrosse", class: "amount", size: 2 %>  
          <span>kWp</span>

          <h2>S  <a id="dialog-3" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <div id="slider-strompreis"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module3", params["user_entry_module3"] || "", id: "amount-strompreis", class: "amount", size: 2 %> 
          <span>cent/kWh</span>

          <h2>St  <a id="dialog-4" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <div id="slider-strompreissteigerung"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module4", params["user_entry_module4"] || "", id: "amount-strompreissteigerung", class: "amount", size: 2 %>
          <span>%</span>

          <h2>E  <a id="dialog-5" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <div id="slider-ertrag"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module5", params["user_entry_module5"] || "", id: "amount-ertrag", class: "amount", size: 2 %>
          <span>kWh/kWp</span>

          <h2>D  <a id="dialog-6" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <div id="slider-degression"></div>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module6", params["user_entry_module6"] || "", id: "amount-degression", class: "amount", size: 2 %>
          <span>pro Jahr %</span>

          <h2 class="text-input">P  <a id="dialog-7" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module7", params["user_entry_module7"] || "", value: "1600", id: "", class: "text-input last-input", size: 2 %>
          <span class="text-input anlagepreis-unit" >pro kWp</span>

          <h2 class="text-input">E  <a id="dialog-8" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module8", params["user_entry_module8"] || "", value: "12", id: "", class: "text-input last-input", size: 2 %>
          <span class="text-input anlagepreis-unit" >cent/kWh</span>

          <h2 class="">?  <a id="dialog-9" href="#" ><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a></h2>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module9", params["user_entry_module9"] || "", value: "ja", id: "", class: "", size: 2 %>

          <%= submit_tag "Berechnen", class: "send_button_1" %>    

  <% end %>
```

I have the `application.html.erb` and `front_end.html.erb` views.

In the `front_end.html.erb` the structure is more or less like this:

```
<%= render "partials/form" %> 

 <script>

  $(function() {

    /Jahresstromverbrauch
    $( "#slider-jahresverbrauch" ).slider({     
      value:3300,
      min: 2000,
      max: 8800,
      step: 100,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount-jahresverbrauch" ).val(ui.value);
      }

    });
    $( "#amount-jahresverbrauch" ).val($( "#slider-jahresverbrauch" ).slider( "value" ));

// in this way I define the other slide bars.

// Ajax call to code1
// Ajax call to code 2 (depends on the results from code1)
// Plotting with highcharts 



});
</script>
```

routes:

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                               Controller#Action

api_v2_energycalcsb_get_values POST /api/v2/energycalcsb/get_values(.:format) api/v2/energycalcsb#get_values
    api_v3_financecalc_get_eco POST /api/v3/financecalc/get_eco(.:format)     api/v3/financecalc#get_eco
         calculation_front_end POST /calculation/front_end(.:format)          calculation#front_end
                          root GET  /                                         calculation#front_end
```

**Question: How can I avoid that after updating the values it maintains these values after clicking the submit button?** I noticed that when clicking the address is called again (loading application.html and front_end.html.erb)

Update: I am trying to avoid a page refresh on submit.
Example: Let say I have a slide bar with a default value (3300). (In my app. all the slide bars are initialized, so just by clicking on the submit button it calculates everything correct). When slicing all the slide bars (in this example let's say 5000), it presents the correct results BUT the slide bars are again set up to the default value (3300), because of the refreshing.

Comment: Please clarify your question, perhaps with an example.  Are you trying to avoid a page refresh on submit or are you having trouble saving updated values to your database and/or displaying them on your form?

Comment: I updated my question @steveklein

Comment: To submit information to the server without a page refresh, you can use Ajax.  To do this, include `remote: true` as a form option.

Comment: Thxs for the comment. The error happens when clicking the submit button, because it calls again the page /calculation/front_end and there in the middle is the <script> which executes again and set up the variables to its default value. The purposes is to recalculate the results sending the new data to the server and receiving back the calculations done in the server, to plot them using highcharts.

Comment: You have a syntax error at `/Jahresstromverbrauch`. You need to use `//` for comments.